# Разработка сервера с обработкой большого числа клиентов

Tags: c++, сервер, сокет, boost

Всем привет. Хотелось бы чтобы ответили на такой, казалось бы не сложный вопрос как разработка "сервера" на c++. 
Есть задача разработать сервер который бы общался с большим числом клиентов(100 и более абонентов).
Какие наиболее правильные подходы к разработке ? Какие инструменты лучше использовать ? На данный момент планирую использовать boost::asio.

Хочется получить информацию от людей уже занимавшихся подобной разработкой. Спасибо.

Comment: 100 клиентов - это не большая нагрузка. Ну совсем не большая (если только они не делают супертяжелой работы). Если знаете буст - смело используйте. Но тут даже самая простая модель поток на клиента будет работать отлично.

Comment: Возможно вам поможет небольшой цикл статей про буст:асио с хабра https://habrahabr.ru/post/192284/. При разработке сервера всегда есть детали: плотность обмена информацией с клиентами, использование совместных данных, синхронизация состояний клиентов, масштабируемость и т.п., которые влияют на выбор модели разработки

Comment: Посмотрите вот [эту](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3083192/) книгу - наверное наиболее полное описание _messaging pattern_ и прочих смежных вещей, думаю, пригодится.